# can't execute pyw on windows

Tags: python, pythonw

I want to hide the console window of a python program, so I change the file extensions to "pyw", but when I open it, the python IDLE show up even though I choose open it with "pythonw.exe"

If I use "pythonw test.py" in cmd, it works.

So I want to know what's wrong with this and how to solve this, thank you.

Comment: reinstall py3.3.3， solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the program that opens python files.

Assuming you're using Windows, right click any python file (in your case any .pyw file, not .py), properties, change `Opens with` to pythonw instead of IDLE

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had multiple version of Python installed that was causing issues. Once I had only had one version, I applied that pythonw.exe was the default for .pyw files and it worked.