# How to open PYW files in Windows 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

Someone gave me a python file to open and use as a resource. The only issue is I don't know anything about python, it's very different from my basic knowledge of coding.

The file is not a normal .py file, but rather a console-less .pyw file. I have imported the newest version of python and installed PySide, but I have had no successful attempts at opening the file.

I was wondering if someone might know how to open this kind of file? Does it need to be somewhere specific?

Comment: pyw should be called by pythonw.exe, if I'm not wront

Comment: Opening through pythonw.exe does nothing. A quick console flash sometimes appears, but nothing pops up and no new task is in the taskmanager.

Comment: how are you running it?

Comment: Trying to run it as C:\\...\python "Code Creator.pyw"

I tried doing it as \pythonw, but it doesn't respond. All I get it errors with both.

Comment: Adding the error message might be helpful ;)

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/21546717/2229132

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the file, click properties, under general it says "opens with:"...
Click the "Change" button to the right of that, and then click more options. On that menu there should be an option called "pythonw" click that. Then on the bottom-right click "apply", then "OK". Then just double-click on the file and it should run with no console window so you won't be able to see it running.